# Causing Uncaught type (reading 'value') error when I click submit

Tags: javascript

I made the zone with `checkbox` list if I type in the value and that entered value is in Database. But when I click submit, it shows `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`. I named both `name` and `id` as `chkzone`. Error is causing in `var chkzone = document.translot.chkzone.value;` line.

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {

$field1name = $row["lotid"];
$field2name = $row["product"];
$field3name = $row["ewsflow"];
$field4name = $row["zone"];
$key = $field1name + ":" + $field2name + ":" + $field3name;

if (!in_array($key, $arr)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th >Lot ID:</th>";
    echo "<td >$field1name</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Product:</th>";
    echo "<td>$field2name</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>EWSFLOW: </th>";
    echo "<td>$field3name</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";

    array_push($arr, $key);
}

echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Zone - $field4name</th>";
echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"chkzone\" id=\"chkzone\" value=\"$zone\"></td>";
//echo "<td>$field4name</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";
```

Below is in JavaScript.

```
    var chkzone = document.translot.chkzone.value;
        if (chkzone == null || chkzone == ""){
            alert("Please choose zone to disable for Correlationwafer.");
            return false;
        }
    
  {
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = SynReqData(reqHttp2,'correlationwafer_result.php?productlotid=' + productlotid + '&chkzone' + chkzone);
      return false;
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a form named `translot`, and is the checkbox inside it?

Comment: Why aren't you testing whether the checkbox is checked? Doesn't that matter?

Comment: @Barmar that error caused when I insert that line in the JavaScript and If I remove that, it cause no error. But it needs to show alert.

Comment: I know. That's why I'm asking whether it's inside a form. `document.translot.chkzone` means the checkbox has to be inside `<form name="translot">`

Comment: checkbox is not inside form name. @Barmar

Comment: Then why did you think `document.translot` would find it?

Comment: FYI, The value of an input will never be `null`, it's always a string. There's no need to test for that.

Comment: @Barmar where should I add that form name? Because form name="translot" is in index page and this checkbox is written in correlationwafer_result.php.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get that error is because `document.translot.chkzone` is undefined. In other words, if you have an element like that in your webpage this must not be the right path to access it.

It's a little challenging to know exactly why that is without seeing your full web page, but given what you're echoing in PHP you might be able to change this:

`var chkzone = document.translot.chkzone.value;`

into this

`var chkzone = document.querySelector('#chkzone').value;`

which should work because you've given your input an id of `chkzone`. If this doesn't work, then please share with us when your javascript code is running, as your issue might be that it's running somewhere before this input element is inserted to the DOM of your webpage.

edit: Also unrelated to your question, but I believe you're missing an `=` sign here: `'&chkzone' + chkzone);` -> `'&chkzone=' + chkzone);`

Comment: I change to document.querySelector but still causing the same error tho.